# Selenium WebDriver Java. Не могу получить Iframe и элементы из него

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

В процессе теста выскакивает окно [image: Desc]

Необходимо нажать на кнопку "no" и продолжить тест.

Как я выяснил, необходимо переключиться на данный фрейм, с него стащить необходимые элементы, их обработать, вернуться на стартовый и продолжить работу.

К сожалению, фрейм я получить не могу, выбивает исключение "No frame element found by name or id"

HTML

```
<iframe ng-non-bindable="" hspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 650px; height: 274px; display: block;" tabindex="0" vspace="0" id="I0_1538262420041" name="I0_1538262420041" src="https://www.google.com/shopping/customerreviews/optin?usegapi=1&amp;merchant_id=113673673&amp;hl=en_US&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wrike.com%2Fresend%2F&amp;order_id=1539472019408&amp;usegapi=1&amp;jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.ru.ORo9oPl_ChI.O%2Fam%3DwQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCN98n80Z9-t_27i1mUuOy6E-T563g%2Fm%3D__features__#id=I0_1538262420041&amp;_gfid=I0_1538262420041&amp;parent=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wrike.com&amp;pfname=&amp;rpctoken=22527236" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Java

```
driver.switchTo().frame("//*[@id=\"I0_1538262420041\"]");
    webElement = driver.findElementByXPath("/html/body/c-wiz/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/span[1]/div/content/span");
    webElement.click();
```

Пробовал добавлять в начало driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); и лишь затем переходить на нужный фрейм по xPath. Не помогает.

Используется firefox webdriver.

Source -> https://www.wrike.com/ -> *get started for free* button.

P.S. Только разбираюсь в Selenium и в вебе в частности, если проблема проста просьба ногами не пинать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так срабатывает:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("I0_1538262420041")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Опытным путем выяснил, что webdriver находит верхний div контейнер фрейма.
Предложенный выше вариант действительно рабочий, но сработал он с xPath вида /html/body/div[6]/div/iframe. Непосредственно по id и name селениум фрейм не находит.
Спасибо за помощь!